# Convert string "AM" or "PM" then add to time without date

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I'm looking for a conversion of just am/pm string into time so I could do comparison between 2 different time of the day. I tried using `time.strptime` or something similar but it seems they all require date as well as time.

My code below:

```
current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "PM"
due_hour = 9
due_minute = 0
due_section = "AM"

import datetime

ct_time = str(datetime.time(current_hour, current_minute))+current_section
print(ct_time)
due_time = str(datetime.time(due_hour, due_minute))+due_section
print(due_time)

ct_time_str = time.strptime(ct_time, '%H:%M:%S') # how to format this to time?

due_time_str= time.strptime(due_time,'%H:%M:%S') # how to format this to time?

if (ct_time_str>due_time_str):
   print("still have time to turn in assignment")
else:
   print("too late")
```

Getting the below error, not sure how to convert to `'time'` from `str`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    ct_time_str = time.strptime(ct_time, '%H:%M:%S')
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error are you getting? My guess is that it is not because of dates, but due to you not parsing `AM/PM` part (`%p` directive). See [ask].

Comment: As @DeepSpace: suggests, use `time.strptime(ct_time, '%H:%M:%S%p')`.

Comment: still getting the same error, says time not defined: ct_time_str = time.strptime(ct_time, '%H:%M:%S%p')
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datetime can be confusing because both the module and class are called datetime.

Change your import to `from datetime import datetime, time`. Also imports should go at the very top, but it's not strictly necessary.

When assigning `ct_time` and `due_time`, you use `str(datetime.time(args))`, it should just be `str(time(args))`.

strptime is from datetime, not time, so change `time.strptime(args)` to `datetime.strptime(args)`

Also like DeepSpace & martineau said, you need to add '%p' to the format string to account for the AM/PM part.

Final code:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "PM"
due_hour = 9
due_minute = 0
due_section = "AM"

ct_time = str(time(current_hour, current_minute))+current_section
print(ct_time)
due_time = str(time(due_hour, due_minute))+due_section
print(due_time)

ct_time_str = datetime.strptime(ct_time, '%H:%M:%S%p')

due_time_str= datetime.strptime(due_time,'%H:%M:%S%p')

if (ct_time_str < due_time_str):
   print("still have time to turn in assignment")
else:
   print("too late")
```

edit:
changed `if (ct_time_str < due_time_str):` to `if (ct_time_str > due_time_str):`

Comment: Thanks code have no error, when I use ```print(due_time_str)``` why does it return 1900-01-01 09:00:00? not 9:00:00 AM.

Comment: The datetime object contains a date AND a time, if you just want the time component use `due_time_str.time()`. Another thing I just noticed is your comparison in the if statement is wrong, should be ct_time greater than.